# Unknown provider: $resouceProvider <- $resouce

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I have searched for a little while and wasn't able to trace the problem

I am getting this error:

```
Unknown provider: $resouceProvider <- $resouce <- apartmentsFactory
```

I am loading scripts in this order:

```
<script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular-base64-upload/dist/angular-base64-upload.min.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/ng-dialog/js/ngDialog.min.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
```

app.js dependencies are as follows:

```
angular.module('rieltorApplication', ['naif.base64', 'ui.router', 'ngResource', 'ngDialog'])
```

services.js

```
angular.module('rieltorApplication')
.constant("baseURL", "http://localhost:3000/")
.factory('apartmentsFactory', ['$resouce', 'baseURL', function($resource, baseURL){

        return $resource(baseURL + "apartments/:id", null, {
            'update': {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });

}])
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('rieltorApplication')
.controller('apartmentsController', ['$scope','ngDialog', 'apartmentsFactory', function($scope, ngDialog, apartmentsFactory){

    //code for the filters button
    $scope.navopen= false;
    $scope.navtracker = function () {
         if($scope.navopen === false)
             $scope.navopen = true;
         else
             $scope.navopen = false;
     }
    //gets app apartments in the data base and sets the view depending on responce 
    $scope.showMenu = false;
    apartmentsFactory.query(
        function (response) {
            $scope.apartments = response;
            $scope.showMenu = true;

        },
        function (response) {
            $scope.message = "Error: " + response.status + " " + response.statusText;
        });

}])
```

Comment: It is $resou**r**ce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, also clear your cache before trying

```
angular.module('rieltorApplication')
.constant("baseURL", "http://localhost:3000/")
.factory('apartmentsFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function($resource, baseURL){

        return $resource(baseURL + "apartments/:id", null, {
            'update': {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });

}])
```

Comment: @JackWolther do you have team viewer?

Comment: yes, I do. How should I give you the ID and password?

Comment: ID:null Pass:null

Comment: @JackWolther no need as estus mentioned there is a spell mistake it should be $resource while injecting to service, check the answer